# Setting up Umbraco as separate front/back end in Azure

Tags: azure, umbraco

I've asked on the Umbraco forums but they're a bit less active there than over here so thought I'd give here a go too.

I've got a requirement to set up Umbraco in Azure. I've read the [Azure Web Apps documentation](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Server-Setup/azure-web-apps) which led me on to the [Load Balancing documentation](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Server-Setup/Load-Balancing/) and eventually the [Flexible Load Balancing documentation](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Server-Setup/Load-Balancing/flexible).

It's quite clear through the documentation that the recommended setup is to have separate Azure App Services for the front and back end, both pointing to a single Azure SQL database.

The bit I feel is missing is the part that actually explains how this is wired up. How does the front end Azure App Service know that it is only responsible for the front end? How is it configured so that back end access not available?

I've read the [Advanced Load Balancing Techniques documentation](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Server-Setup/Load-Balancing/flexible-advanced) but I don't really understand how this works. It talks about executing some of the code on the master server and some on the replica servers. Does this mean two different code bases for the front/back-end?

I can very easily create two App Services and deploy the Umbraco website to both of them but I'm not clear on how to make each of them aware of their responsibilities and put in place the infrastructure to create this separation.

If it's explained in the documentation somewhere, please feel free to point me towards it because I haven't been able to find it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I'm not familiar with Umbraco per se however usually the database is exposed to the backend directly with the front end having to access the data through calls to the database, load balancers job as the name implies is to send the request to the best available service, it's just a speculation but you might have misunderstood the deployment strategy, what you might need is  
1- web app and web app service plan to host umbraco 
2- Azure sql database instance

load balancers if you are planning to scale Horizontally so you can have multiple web apps in different web apps plans.

Comment: I might be able to help more if you can share more details about the architecture you are planning to deploy there is too much room for speculation in the description.

Comment: The complete architecture I require is explained [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/solutions/architecture/medium-umbraco-web-app/).

Umbraco's diagram of the setup is [here](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Server-Setup/Load-Balancing/images/flexible-load-balancing.png).

So it doesn't look like a load balancer is used to direct users to the admin/back-end application. I'm pretty sure somewhere in the documentation it's stated that the admin server should **not** be behind a load balancer because it could potentially lead to concurrency issues.